# Creating New Users

Tags: login

I already looked some topics, but I couldn't find the answer to my doubts.
I am learning Linux and doing some exercises here in **Ubuntu 14.04** LTS.

I want to create a new user. After the creation process, it says "account disabled". I select "enable account", put the asked admin password, but nothing happens.
The only thing got was login this user with no password.

I need to put a password, enable this account and test it.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't ask for the admin password when you click `account disabled` it asks you to set a password for the user. You enter a password hit ok and its enabled.

Comment: To add user from terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) "adduser" and to delete user from terminal "deluser".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a user use :

```
sudo adduser user
```

To create change password for a user :

```
sudo passwd user
```

To enable a user :

```
sudo passwd -u user
```

**u** means unlock .

Comment: Thanks ! The First and second lines worked ! The third command, I had to type "passwd -u user", but the permission was denied.

Comment: But I just tested the login and it's working.

Comment: your user is unlocked , that command is when its disabled  , if this is your answer dont forget to mark as an answer, ty

Comment: you should know that the first command is what you need , it will create user and password and enabled it .